# CSS gets messed up after Ajax page load

Tags: css, ajax, jquery, wordpress

I have a website in wordpress. I recently download a plugin called Advanced Ajax Page Loader. It refreshes you content when clicked on other page without refreshing the whole site(header, footer). I tried to get my answer from plugins developer and wordpress support forum, but none responded.

I read that if ajax jquery call is used then all scripts should be reloaded again, for that the plugin have a place where I should put those codes. Until that everything works correctly, except one thin. When I go from a category to category, everything works fine, but when I open  a single Post it completely screws up all my css for that page, when I refresh it, everything looks fine but then again, if I open one of the big categories with many posts, then that pages css is messed up.

I though that I could somehow refresh whole css by putting some code in the "Reload code" box, but I have no idea how to do that using scripts. English isn't my native language, therefore I'm having difficulty finding my answer on google, I tried, but my vocabulary is limited. How can I do it?

Comment: Is the `css` for this page not included on the other pages?

Answer (score 0):

are you adding CSS classes to your elements via Javascript? If so, then the styles you add will only affect those elements which are part of the DOM at that point in time, so you might be experiencing a race condition, that actually happens to work in Chrome and Safari, but not Firefox.

second try to validate your markup and CSS and see if you have any error in your css syntax ?